# How to access Shadow Root from within the ShadowDom in closed mode?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I have one script, outside the ShadowDom, that attaches a shadowRoot to an element and fills the Shadow Dom. The mode of shadowRoot is closed. I am not adding the

```
var variable = element.attachShadow({mode:'closed'})
```

variable to the window scope, it's within a function.

A script within the Shadow Dom needs to access other elements of that same Shadow Dom. Is there a way to do that? I tried,

```
document.currentScript.parentNode
```

But document.currentScript returns null.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you storing CODE in the shadowDOM? Code is not sandboxed like HTML and CSS when inside shadowDOM. It is still run at a global level. This is different than how the `<iframe>` works.

If you are going to this level of attempted segregation of code then just use a real WebComponent and do everything in that class.

If you still have to continue to do it how you are doing it then you need to have a way to pass `variable` (The shadowRoot variable) into the code you are placing in the shadowDOM.

**UPDATE - Aug 3, 2020**

If other code needs to access a closed shadow DOM then the code that created the `shadowRoot` needs to save off the `shadowRoot` as a variable and then pass that variable to the other functions. Or, you need to create a closed scope within JavaScript and store the `shadowRoot` in that scope. If all other functions are within that scope then they will have access to the variable that points to the `shadowRoot`.

Below is some EXAMPLE code that shows how to create a scope.

```js
const publicInterface = (function() {
  var shadowRoot;
  
  function createShadowDom() {
    shadowRoot = ...
  }
  
  function doSomethingElse() {
    let a = shadowRoot.querySelector('.something');
    if (a) {
    }
  }
  
  return {
    createShadowDom,
    doSomethingElse
  }
})();

publicInterface.createShadowDom();
publicInterface.doSomethingElse();
```

The variable `shadowRoot` is protected inside the scope and can not be accessed by any outside code. But any function inside the scope, like `createShadowDom` and `doSomethingElse` can access `shadowRoot`.